# Why do I have all the sudden a user called "postgres" on my login screen?

Tags: login-screen

It appeared just like that, a quick searched suggested that it's a user created by a database application but why is it on my login screen?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All users above user id 999 are shown on the login screen.
Set a user id below 999 for the user postgres with `sudo usermod -u 999 postgres`.

Or you can add the user to the ignore list with:
`sudo nano /etc/lightdm/users.conf`
find the line `hidden-users=` and add postgres to that line.

Answer (score 1):

As soon as the user id is greater than 999, it shows.

Comment: A method how to remove the user from the login-screen would be nice.

Comment: I agree with ByteCommand, though technically the answer addresses the question.

Answer (score 1):

whenever an user has an `id` greater than 999, it shows at the login screen, to remove this you an reduce the login `id` for doing this you have to install `user and accounts options` of gnome desktop for this

```
$sudo apt-get install gnome-system-tools
```

and after installing this you will be get

[image]

and then

[image]

and then goto

- advanced settings and decrease the id of the selected user